# Dividing Field by COUNT of Character in Substring

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

First off I'm 100% open to alternatives assuming they achieve what I'm trying to do...

Here's an example of some data I'm working with from the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.VW_CODE WHERE RIGHT(Code, 3) = '001' AND [Date] = '20200516'

|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
|  Code  |    Date    |  Cost  | Length | TraNum |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
| P 1001 | 2020-05-16 |   15   |   50   |   641  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
| P 2001 | 2020-05-16 |   5    |   50   |   641  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
| P 3001 | 2020-05-16 |   7    |   50   |   641  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------| 
| P 4001 | 2020-05-16 |   10   |   50   |   641  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
| P 1001 | 2020-05-16 |   11   |   110  |   774  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
| P 2001 | 2020-05-16 |   16   |   110  |   774  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
| P 3001 | 2020-05-16 |   8    |   110  |   774  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------| 
| P 4001 | 2020-05-16 |   15   |   110  |   774  |
```

Code is a VARCHAR(6), and is concatenated from 3 other fields. Broken down it's 'a ' + 'b' + 'ccc'. The issue is that the 3rd character (b) is "duplicating" values for Date, Length and TraNum, although it's behavior for Cost is correct as there is an allocation happening behind the scenes. What I want to achieve is to divide Length (and only Length), by the number of b's per ccc, date, tranum.

Example output of what I'd like it to look like:

```
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
|  Code  |    Date    |  Cost  | Length | TraNum |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
| P 1001 | 2020-05-16 |   15   |   12.5 |   641  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
| P 2001 | 2020-05-16 |   5    |   12.5 |   641  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
| P 3001 | 2020-05-16 |   7    |   12.5 |   641  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------| 
| P 4001 | 2020-05-16 |   10   |   12.5 |   641  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
| P 1001 | 2020-05-16 |   11   |   27.5 |   774  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
| P 2001 | 2020-05-16 |   16   |   27.5 |   774  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
| P 3001 | 2020-05-16 |   8    |   27.5 |   774  |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------| 
| P 4001 | 2020-05-16 |   15   |   27.5 |   774  |
```

The key caveat here being that the divisor must be dynamic to the number of b's per ccc. If modifying that query to RIGHT(Code, 3) = '002' results in 'P 1002' through 'P 7002' then Length should be divided by 7 as that's the distinct count of b's for ccc = 002.

As I said, I'm sure there's some potential alternative which involves RANK() OVER Partition BY etc, etc, so if it achieves this I'm all ears.

EDIT: I should probably add that this is a very simplified look of the view, focused on the key fields. The script for the view is one of the most complicated I've seen with tons of derived data, so my goal is to wrap the entire view script in a CTE and do the SELECT of the CTE fields with the calculation for Length there. I don't really want to play around with the main body of the SELECT.

Thanks!

Comment: Aside: Not sure why you tagged this `ssms`. It is more useful to identify the database software, e.g. `sql-server`. SSMS is a tool that can connect to a wide variety of databases.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, it would be like this.

```
SELECT 
    Code,
    Date,
    Cost,
    cast(Length as decimal) / count(*) over(partition by Date, Length, TraNum) as Length,
    TraNum 
FROM dbo.VW_CODE WHERE RIGHT(Code, 3) = '001' AND [Date] = '20200516'
```